# Range sensor layer marked obstacles cannot be cleared by LaserScan

Tags: ros, 2dlaserscan, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Just a quick question. I found that the obstacles marked by ultrasound (plugin RangeSensorLayer) cannot be cleared by Laser Scan on costmap. But these obstacles can be cleared by ultrasound itself. On the other side, Laser Scan marked obstacles cannot be cleared by ultrasound either according to my experiment. I use ROS kinetic. Is my observation correct or there is something wrong in my configuration of experiment? Any insight would be highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Gerry

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364003/range-sensor-layer-marked-obstacles-cannot-be-cleared-by-laserscan/) by [Gerry](https://answers.ros.org/users/52784/gerry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OK, after some study and experiments, I guess I find the reason. The obstacle marked/cleared by ultrasound is performed by range_sensor_layer::RangeSensorLayer while the obstacle cleared by Laser Scan is implemented by costmap2d::ObstacleLayer. It is simply that they are at different layers so that one cannot be cleared by the other.

I provide my findings here so other people who might face similar problem can get some insight from this post. The concept of layers used by costmap is the key to this problem.

Best regards,
Gerry

---

Originally posted by [Gerry](https://answers.ros.org/users/52784/gerry/) with karma: 23 on 2020-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1